# How to add multiple users in Multi-user People Picker field (Person or Group Field)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I want to add multiple users in multi-picker person field in SharePoint list.
I tried below code but always getting an error that:

> New-object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```
$ClientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Securedpw = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$ClientContext.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $Securedpw)
$web = $ClientContext.Web 
$list= $web.lists.GetByTitle($listName)
$ClientContext.Load($list)
$ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
$ListItemCreationInformation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
$ListItem= $list.AddItem($ListItemCreationInformation)

$UserAccounts="domain\arzoo; domain\ashwin"
$UserAccountsColl = $UserAccounts -split ';'
$UserCollection = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValueCollection
foreach($UserAccount in $UserAccountsColl)
{    
   #Get the User
    $User=$web.EnsureUser($UserAccount)

    #Add to collection
    $UserFieldValue = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue($Web, $User.ID, $User.LoginName)
    $UserCollection.Add($UserFieldValue)
}

#update the Multiple value Person or Group field
$ListItem[$FieldName] = $UserCollection
$ListItem.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PnP Powershell](https://github.com/sharepoint/pnp-powershell/releases) for this easily.

```
#region Variables 
$Username = "lee@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
$Password = "pw" 
$siteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee" 

#endregion Variables

#region Credentials 
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials
$users = "user1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", "user2@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
Set-PnPListItem -List "MyList" -Identity 9 -Values @{"User"=$users}
```